# group homomorphism on the rationals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $f:Q->Q$ be a group homomorphism where Q is the group of rationals under addition.

Prove that an integer $x$, $f(x)=xf(1)$.

$f(x)=f(1.x)$ but how do you get $f(1.x)=xf(1)$?

Comment: Why are you claiming that $f(x)=f(1.x)$?  Where do decimals come into the problem?  Also, why are you trying to show that $f(1.x)=xf(1)$?  Hint: prove that $f(x)=xf(1)$ for a natural number $x$ using induction on $x$, and then use the fact that $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

Comment: @Hayden By $1.x$, OP probably means $1\times x$. (In many countries, the decimal separator is the comma, and the dot is sometimes used for multiplication.)

Comment: @fkraiem Thanks, I had a feeling that that might have been the case, but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $f(1)=a$.   Then for any natural number m,  you have $f(m)=f(1+1+1...+1.)$ m times, which by homomorphism breaks down into $f(m)=a+a+a+a+a....+a$ $m$ copies of $a$, which is $f(m)=ma$.

Now, take a negative integer,  by homomorphism properties you have $f(-m)=-f(m)$, so the above holds.

Now take a natural number $n$,  and look at $f(1)=f(1/n+1/n+1/n+....+1/n)$,  $n$ copies of $1/$n,  so we have $a=nf(1/n)$,  or $f(1/n)=a/n$.     Combine this to with above to get $f(m/n)=m/n*a$, which is exactly what you wanted to prove, since any rational number can be expressed as $m/n$.

Comment: of course, knew I was missing something easy

Comment: @user108605 no problem, this is a pretty classical example.   Also, it leads to the obvious followup that you have an isomorphism if and only if the constant is not 0, and the group of automorphisms under function composition is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of the rationals.